# Create excel graphs from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, reporting-services, ssis

I have the following requirement,

I have to run a stored procedure, which actually creates the table and inserts the values in it by fetching values from various places. At the end of the procedure it will invoke SSIS in turn and generate an excel file out of it. So far so good for me, but the requirement also suggests to create a graph out of the values generated in the excel. This is the one I am really puzzled on how to do it.

I know it can be done with SSRS, but I would like to know other ways as we have only SSIS with us and SSRS is totally out of scope.

I have tried various ways (created a dynamic graph already in the excel template and let the new values generated renders the graph but it does not work sadly. :(). I cannot create graphs with the empty excel templates that I feed to SSIS.

Excel is the problem here , it does not allows any pre-defined graphs in it. It always expects a value to create a graphs. I can also go for a VBA macro option,(like creating a button and let the user click the button to generate graphs) but I am not really sure if it is a feasible one?

Excel experts please help !

I might like sound like an amateur but please pardon me as I am new to SSIS and none of my colleagues have an idea on how to do it and I could not get anything with the research I have done, which is a bit frustrating though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PowerPivot to connect to your table and create a PivotChart :

1. Add PowerPivot to Excel
2. Open a new workbook in Excel and then click the PowerPivot tab.
3. Click the PowerPivot Window button on the ribbon.
4. In the Get External Data group, click From Database, and then select From SQL Server.
5. Click the Browse button, select the appropriate SQL Server database, and then click Next:

   At this point, you have two options.

   - You can import data from a table that is in the database or from a query that is in the database. If you do not want all of the records from a table, you can apply a filter to limit the records that are returned.
   - You can import the data by using an SQL query. Unlike the first option, where you can return data based on a query that is defined in the database, you use the second option to specify an SQL query in PowerPivot that is executed against the database to retrieve the records.
     The next steps show how to retrieve data from tables and queries in the database.
6. Select the option, Select from a list of tables…, and then click Next.
7. Select the tables that you want to import:
8. By default, all of the columns and records in the selected tables are returned. To filter the records or specify a subset of the columns, click Preview & Filter.
9. To automatically include tables that are related to the selected tables click Select Related Tables.
10. Click Finish to load the data into PowerPivot.

Comment: Good comment, beat me to the punch.

Comment: Hi Riadh, Thanks for the response, I can add the powerpivot to my excel, but I may need to send this excel to multiple persons who have no access to the backend sql server at all. I can open the excel and can connect to the backend database, but I want everything to be automated. Is that possible with this powerpivot option ?

Comment: Hi, Yes you can use the authentification sql server.

Comment: Hi riadh, to give more picture on the requirement, just imagine a scheduled job that runs at 9 am in the morning. This job should send a spreadsheet with data and the chart attached in a mail to n number of users. In Power pivot there seems to be a manual intervention (someone has to go and open the excel in order to fetch the data from the server, rite?). Also the n number of users are not even aware of the sql server and dont know anything about the username and password of the server) Really sorry, it would be really helpful if you give some light on that part.

Comment: Ah ok I get it , I will create an example and I will tell you if I find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to use Pivot Charts, with source as a named table in excel. Make sure you set the options for the Pivot chart to refresh automatically when opening the excel file.

Using this excel template, make sure you populate your data into the same table / or create the table, which Pivot chart will refer to , and you are done. Have an email action towards the end of your flow, to send the excel file to the users. As soon as they open the file, the Pivot chart, will be refreshed with the new data you have pushed into the named table.

Hope this helps.